# How to use CIWarpKernel Coordinate system correctly?

Tags: ios, core-image

I am trying to build a custom warp kernel in ios .

I have this kernel code

```
var kernelCode =
        " kernel vec2 partialFlip(vec2 center, float width, float height) {   " + "\n" +
        " vec2 p = destCoord();    " + "\n" +
        " float x = width - p.x;   " + "\n" +
        " float y = height - p.y;   " + "\n" +
        " return vec2(x, y); }  ";

        kernel = CIWarpKernel(string: kernelCode);
```

I want to flip a region vertically and horizontally when user taps on an image. The region is calculated with the help of the tap of the user and a constant width. Just when I tap the image, the entire image turns into a single color, I assume that every pixel is taking it's new color from only one pixel,  For using the kernel I am calling

```
 var width = radius;
 var height = radius;   
 var roi  = CGRectMake(center.X - width / 2,center.Y - height / 2, width, height);
    return kernel.applyWithExtent(roi, roiCallback: {(n : Int32, rect: CGRect) -> CGRect in return rect; }, inputImage: image, arguments: [center, width, height])!;
```

My center and radius comes from the image coordinate system. 
   Am I missing something here? Should I scale everything down to [0,1] ?

Answer (score 2):

The Core Image coordinates are in non-normalized pixels.
The coordinates are Cartesian (ie. origin is at the lower left)